# Send mail on New product add and on edit existing product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, email

I want to sent one email when we adding new product & another different email when we editing present product?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**config.xml**

Add your template here

```
app\locale\en_US\template\email\templatename.html



 <events>
    <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <yourmodule>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                        <method>catalog_product_save_after</method>
                    </yourmodule>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
 <template>
        <email>
            <my_custom_template module="module">
                <label>template name</label>
                <file>templatename.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </my_custom_template>

        </email>
    </template>
```

**Observer.php**

```
class YourNamespace_YourModule_Model_Observer
{
public function catalog_product_save_after($observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        // Your mail code
    }
```

Comment: How  to know new product action or edit product action

Comment: Before send mail you need to check this product id it's available or not in Database

Comment: product id shows both action or do you know how check this condition code?

Comment: simple if product id is available that's edit product else it's new product

Comment: First check this code you get mail or not after save product

Comment: for new product we will send product url those shows in frontend but not get product url & inventory like stock availability & qty?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48701/discussion-between-magikvishal-and-kothari).